# Powershell expensive parsing

Tags: syntax, powershell

Heres a little segment from a script Im writing;

```
Get-Content $tempDir\$todaysLog | Where-Object { $_ -match "" } |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
    $fields = [regex]::split($_,'@|\s+')
    Add-Content -Path $importSource2\$todaysLog -value ($($fields[0]) + "`t"  + $($fields[1]) + "`t" + $($fields[2]) + " " + $($fields[3])+ "`t" + "<*sender*@"+($($fields[5])) + "`t" + "<*recipient*@"+($($fields[7])))
    }
```

Sorry about the wrapping, essentially it tokenises the elements of the file into an an array then writes out certain elements with some other text around it.  The purpose is to replace sentitive sender/recipient information with something meaningless.

heres a sample of the logfile I'm parsing;

10.197.71.28    SG  02012009 00:00:00      <['recip@kpmg.com.sg']>

Obviously Ive replaced the address info in my sample.  The above segment works just fine althgogh Im conscious its very expensive. Can anything think of something that would be less expensive, perhaps a select-string to replace the text rather than tokenising/rewriting it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
cat $tempDir\$todaysLog |
  %{ [regex]::Replace($_, "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\s<\[')[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}'\]>)", '*sender*$1*recipients*$2', "IgnoreCase") } > $importSource2\$todaysLog
```

The log entries must look like the sample line (especially the sender@kpmg.com <['recip@kpmg.com.sg']> part).

---

**Edit** : I've done some benchmarking (1 mo file (~15000 lines sample like)):

### Andy Walker's solution (using *split*) -> **18,44s**

```
Measure-Command {

Get-Content $tempDir\$todaysLog | Where-Object { $_ -match "" } |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
    $fields = [regex]::split($_,'@|\s+')
    Add-Content -Path $importSource2\$todaysLog -value ($($fields[0]) + "`t"  + $($fields[1]) + "`t" + $($fields[2]) + " " + $($fields[3])+ "`t" + "<*sender*@"+($($fields[5])) + "`t" + "<*recipient*@"+($($fields[7])))
    }

}
```

### Dangph's solution (using *replace*) -> **18,16s**

```
Measure-Command {

Get-Content $tempDir\$todaysLog | Where-Object { $_ -match "" } |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
    $s2 = $_ -replace "\t[^@\t']+@", "`t*sender*@"
    $s3 = $s2 -replace "\<\['.+@", "<['*recipient*@"
    Add-Content -Path $importSource2\$todaysLog -value $s3
    }

}
```

### Madgnome's solution (using *regex*) -> **6,16s**

```
Measure-Command {

cat $tempDir\$todaysLog |
  %{ [regex]::Replace($_, "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\s<\[')[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}'\]>)", '*sender*$1*recipients*$2', "IgnoreCase") } > $importSource2\$todaysLog

}
```

Comment: Interesting results. What do you mean by "1 mo"? How many lines is that? I'd be curious to know what size files Andy Walker is dealing with.

Comment: To time commands, use Measure-Command like so: 
Measure-Command { 1..1000 }

Answer (score 0):

```
$s1 = "10.197.71.28 SG  02012009 00:00:00   sender@kpmg.com <['recip@kpmg.com.sg']>"
$s2 = $s1 -replace "\t[^@\t']+@", "`t*sender*@"
$s3 = $s2 -replace "\<\['.+@", "<['*recipient*@"
write-host $s3
```

I'm assuming that all the log entries look like the sample line. If they don't, then we may have to be a bit more sophisticated.

**Note** that if you copy-and-paste the above code, you may need to manually re-insert the tab character before "sender" in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using Powershell as the engine for large file size log parsing. I would use logparser.exe (you have a space delimited entry that could be converted to a csv) and then use import-csv in Powershell to recreate a Powershell object.  From there you can strip and replace fields (on a per object basis).  Powershell is glue not fuel.  Using it to parse large logs of any size is not quite downright folly, but will be expensive for you and the CPU. Although, Lee Holmes has an excellent Convert-TextObject.ps1 from his book examples at http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596528492/ ,  you want a log parsing engine of some type to handle the heavy lifting.